# Expresión regular ?=

Tags: javascript, regex

necesito crear una expresión regular de JS, para insertar uno o dos apellidos en un formulario.

Llevo esto --> `^[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]*(([\s])(?=[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ])*)?$`

El problema es el espacio, que necesito que no lo use si no hay otro nombre delante, para ello he leido que sirve x(?=y) pero no consigo implementarlo no se aplica bien la expresión (?=)

Answer (score 0):

Al final resultaba que la regex tan solo agarraba coincidencias, y lo que venía después que era otro texto (`[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]`) no lo cogía por que solo hacía de "if" y no como valor, por lo que lo he duplicado y ha servido

Ha quedado así

```
^[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]*(([\s])(?=[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ])([A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ])*(?=[\s]))?
```